# obtener valor de columna datatable oculta

Tags: javascript, datatables

Hola lo que quiero haces es basicamente lo que dice el titulo. Vi que hay algunas preguntas similares, pero no me resultaron para mi caso.

```
fila        = $(this).closest("tr");            
id   = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text());              
nombre      = fila.find('td:eq(1)').text();
apellido    = fila.find('td:eq(2)').text();
dni         = fila.find('td:eq(3)').text();
```

y cuando alguna de las columnas esta oculta en el datatable, me toma el valor de la siguiente y no el que corresponde. Queria saber como puedo hacer para tomar ese valor
Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código de tu tabla? Lo que se me ocurre fácilmente es asignarle un id a las celdas; aunque eso dependerá de cómo llenas los datos de la misma. Por ejemplo si obtienes los datos desde un JSON, entonces podrías leer los valores desde el JSON y no desde el HTML.

Answer (score 0):

gracias por responder.
Si te referis a como cargo la tabla es asi:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var nro_socio, opcion;
opcion = 4;

tablaSocios = $('#tablaSocios').DataTable({  
       "autoWidth": false,
       "ajax":{            
        "url": "acciones/acciones_socios.php", 
        "method": 'POST', //usamos el metodo POST
        "data":{opcion:opcion}, //envio opcion 4 para que haga un SELECT
        "dataSrc":""
    },
    "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast":"Último",
                    "sNext":"Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                 },
                 "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
            },
    "columns":[
        {"data": "nro_socio"},
        {"data": "nombre"},
        {"data": "apellido"},
        {"data": "dni"},
        {"data": "fecha_nac", "width": "100px"},
        {"data": "telefono"},
        {"data": "descripcion_socio"},
        {"data": "estado"},
        {"data": "descripcion_cuota"},
        {"defaultContent": "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons'>delete</i></button><button class='btn btn-info btn-sm btnCobrar'><i class='material-icons'>business_center</i></button></div></div>"},
        {"data": "email" , "searchable": false  , "visible": false },
        {"data": "id_tipo_socio" ,"searchable": false  , "visible": false},
        {"data": "id_estado" ,"searchable": false  , "visible": false},
        {"data": "id_tipo_cuota" ,"searchable": false  , "visible": false}
    ]
});
```